# Cannot see events in AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: aws-code-deploy

My CodeDeploy deployment is failing. Usually I'm able to see the event list on each instances, and see which ones failed/passed. 
This no longer works, and the event list is empty. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 7):

As Jonathan Turpie mentions, you should probably troubleshoot if the instance is taking care of your deployment.

You could first try to troubleshoot via AWS CLI, `aws deploy get-deployment --deployment-id d-USUAELQEX`. It might return error codes that will help you to tweak your setting and succeed with your deployment. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/get-deployment.html

If your EC2 instance actually handles the deployment. Edit the `/etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml` and set `:verbose:` to `true` on your EC2 instance.

Try to deploy again and open `codedeploy-agent.log` at `/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent` and see if you are able to see anything there. Read more here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/host-cleanup.html

Answer (score 2):

You may not be able to see events if the deployment didn't get far enough. For example, there was a problem getting the list of instances due to IAM configuration or your instance isn't responding to commands.

Comment: Good point. @EugeneMi the codedeploy-agent logs [mentioned above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30941337/1177832) worked for me (revealed I had misconfigured IAM trust policy, [similar to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551863/amazon-codedeploy-deployment-failed)).

Answer (score 1):

Check the codedeploy-agent-log.txt file. it might have some more info about the underground issue. in a windows machine you find it under

> C:\ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy\log

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jonathan, you might not have the right configuration for your IAM configurations. Check that your IAM role has the policy "AWSCodeDeployRole".

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the code deploy agent is not running. Make sure the code deploy agent is running:

```
sudo service codedeploy-agent status
```