# AWS CodePipeline Fails due to too few healthy instances

Tags: amazon-web-services

Trying this out.. but keeps failing with:

```
too few healthy instances are available for deployment
```

Here's what I've done.  I started an instance.. up and running fine.  I have ssh'd to it etc.  I am simply trying to deploy a helloworld node app. My buildspec.yaml does nothing... Artifacts are created fine in my S3 bucket... but it fails on codeDeploy.

(I've tried Deployment configurationCodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime AND Deployment configurationCodeDeployDefault.HalfATime.  Same result...)

I then added an instance.. to see if having 2 instances would increase the chances of getting this to deploy :-) Same error.

I must be missing something very obvious here.

The GIT step works, the build step works.. just the actual deployment fails...

Thanks in advance.. I'll keep trying...

Comment: Are you using an Auto Scaling group? Could you describe how it's configured (specifically the min and max capacity)?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying.. No.. no auto scaling group.. is that required?

Comment: Tried bluegreen with auto scaling.  All fails. This is a 1 line nodejs app.  AWS can't deploy this? IBM Bluemix is 1 click.  Azure the same.... Very disappointed (so far) in AWS -- and it holds on to 40%?  Heck Heroku works :-) No worries.. I will not be recommending AWS to my employer

Comment: Does CodeDeploy give you a more detailed error message? Does the deployment succeed if you deploy directly using CodeDeploy?

Comment: Tried using codedeploy directly... same...   giving up now... only message I get is the too few healthy instances msg.  tx for the response.

Comment: You might find these helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551863/amazon-codedeploy-deployment-failed and https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=759098&tstart=0.

Comment: So I ended up not giving up :-) . I now have a working environment that allows me to deploy from git.  Here's what I did...

I used ElasticBeanstalk (nodejs) and the eb cli to deploy.  That worked.  (Not for MAC the pip install didn't work for me.. use homebrew)

Suits my purposes.  But the docs are wrong... there is no such command as eb branch.  

eb branch
usage: eb (sub-commands ...) [options ...] {arguments ...}
eb: error: unrecognized arguments: branch

Just do eb init... then eb deploy.  Works for me.  As far as codedeploy and the pipeline .. I'll get back to that someday...

Comment: Cheers Aaron.. will take a look...

Comment: Well mystery solved.. got it to work.  The issue?  Missing the appspec.yml -- and deployed the codedeploy agent on the instance.

Happy now :-) . tx

Comment: That'll do it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Missing the appspec.yml -- and deployed the codedeploy agent on the instance.

[Link to install instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install.html#codedeploy-agent-operations-install-linux)